# "execvp: no such file or directory" when attempting taskset on a running process

Tags: command-line, parameters, affinity

I have a process, PID `7150`.

I want to assign the process to core #4 of my system.  (Core numbering starts with zero, so the fourth core should be core #3)

I know I can do this by using [Taskset](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/taskset1.html).  However, whenever I try, I get the following:

```
steve@rosie:~$ taskset -p 7150
pid 7150's current affinity mask: f
steve@rosie:~$ taskset -c 3 -p 7150
execvp: No such file or directory
failed to execute -p
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper format for the command is:

```
taskset -pc 3 7150
```